# CodeIgniter web application loading very slow

Tags: php, codeigniter

My CodeIgniter Application was working fine on online server but directly without any modification of application the web application loading greater than a minute.

Same i have transffer the application to local server same issue is comming on local server web application is loading very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your browser developer tools Network tab to check if it is just the request for the HTML document that is slow. If it is, then use [CodeIgniter's debugging features](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/testing/debugging.html) and  benchmarks to find out which part of the application is slow. When CodeIgniter is that slow, it is probably because it is calling some database or API that is slow.

If other requests are slow, such as for images and css, then it is not an issue with CodeIgniter, but with your server/local setup.