# Codeigniter view load issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When Im using

```
echo modules::run('layout');
```

it takes more than a minute to load the view, but when using

```
$this->load->view('layout');
```

it's working fine. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Why do you want to load a view this way? Are you using a third party library, like an HMVC project, which needs to call a module with *modules::run('layout');*?

Comment: I have HMVC project in which the third party library are used and now the project redirect is very slow performance when change the code to $this->load->view('layout'); the application is working fine so what is the reason behind this when im use the $this->load->view() instead of echo modules::run('layout')

Comment: Did the answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930756/codeigniter-web-application-loading-very-slow) help with this one?